# .onDelete causes a crash because out of index

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

Does anyone know why this code cause a fatal error: Index out of range, when I try to delete an item from the list? At the moment I am able to create more textfields and populate them but unable to delete anything without the app crashing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct options: View {

@State var multiOptions = [""]

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(multiOptions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("Enter your option...", text: $multiOptions[index])
            }
            .onDelete(perform: removeRow)
        }
        
        Button {
            multiOptions.append("")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        }

    }

}
func removeRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    multiOptions.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}

}
```

Comment: As per my previous answer, don't use `@State`. SwiftUI views are structs and therefore immutable, so they are recreated when they need to update. Use a separate model object to hold your array with `@StateObject`

Comment: Watch demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21 `indices`and `multiOptions[index]` are considered unsafe for this reason.

Comment: For your info, your code as is, works very well for me on macos 12.beta9, xcode 13.beta5 (not release), 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices. It maybe different on older systems. However I would recommend you re-structure your code, and use the advices already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with custom Binding:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var multiOptions = [""]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(multiOptions.indices, id: \.self) { index in

                    TextField("Enter your option...", text: Binding(get: { return multiOptions[index] },
                                                                    set: { newValue in multiOptions[index] = newValue }))
  
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRow)
            }
            
            Button {
                multiOptions.append("")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    func removeRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        multiOptions.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems hard to believe, but apparently the naming of an attribute in the entity as "id" is the cause of this behavior. I changed the name of the UUID attribute to "myID" and the deletions now work. The list view still does not work at all in the preview, but it does now work in the simulator and with a device.

Comment: Are you sure you just post the right answer for the right question? It seems you send some other answer for other question as an answer here! I would say you are in wrong party!

Comment: yes i just run it on xcode 12 it fixed

Comment: So why not share your tried code here!

Comment: There is no `...naming of an attribute in the entity ` in the code. What are you talking about?
Your answer does not address this question.